# Microservices store User info between services

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design

For example I have a post service. At UI I need to show post and userinfo (username and id for redirect to user page)

Options:

1. Should I store username and id in post service. (When every user register to system I will send subset detail to post service via RabbitMQ). (Total Request from UI= 1)
2. I will store only Id of user(AR). And at UI component fetch user with id(Total Request from UI=2)

Comment: I would recommend option 1, unless username can be changed. In this instance, the decision is harder, and it *may* be better to do option 2.

Comment: I would go with option 1. If username can change juste publish an event and listen to it from post service to update data. Also entities should not be shared accross services so the post bounded context should probably have a "poster" entity which is a different entity than "user".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are OK. The decision is based on how you map the concepts between different boundary contexts. The [patterns](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/context-mapping-in-domain-driven-design-9063465d2eb8) are:

- Anticorruption Layer
- Shared Kernel
- Open Host Service(option 2)
- Separate Ways
- Customer Supplier
- Conformist
- Partenership
- Published Language
- ...

It is not only the personal preference, but also about the organization structure([The Conway's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law)).

If both the two contexts(post and user) are controlled by your team, you could choose either of them. Considering the complexity of the option 1, I prefer option 2 since it's very straight. Start from the easier one then involve your architecture is always a good idea.

Comment: Great answer, but respectfully disagree with your recommendation. I would go for option 1 myself.

Comment: @tomredfern The option 1 including a data synchronization mechanism which increase the complexity. However, if username never change then store username redundantly looks great. But I'm afraid there will be more and more things have to be save redundantly along with the system involving. Then you will need to sync data. Anyway, the answer would be "It depends"...